# How to make a GPT (Data Partition) bootable?

Tags: uefi, gpt, efi

I had a Windows 10 on a GPT partitioned disk and I created a Ghost image of the Operating System like I had done in the past.

Now I got a larger HDD which is a GPT partitioned disk as well and I split it into 2 partitions, which are being reported in 'Easeus Partition' as GPT (Data Partition). Then I restored the .GHO image into one of these partitions but the problem I'm now having is that I cannot see how to make this new partition bootable.

I've been researching the whole afternoon but I don't understand much about the subject and I cannot see what's happening or what I need to try. If you could please give me some direction to see how I could restore the old .GHO image in the new partition and make this one bootable please? Better if there are tools to help with this, as I might make some error if it's too technical...

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the required EFI partition?  It sounds like you didn't create an image of the entire disk but only that of a single partition which isn't enough.

Comment: ^ This. UEFI boots from an EFI system partition. Is does not boot from a generic data partition.

Comment: ah, I just checked my backups and I made a copy of the individual partitions that came with the disk, although I didn't understand their meaning. 

I've got a small partition of 260MB as a .GHO image as well, which is marked as EFI. Could I restore this in another partition on my new HDD? Although if I've then got 2 partitions in this new HDD, not sure if the EFI one is going to know and be linked about the Data Partition somehow? or could I use any program to link them if I restore them both?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to install a dummy UEFI windows 10, and then replace OS partition with ghost image. (You will have to do it from another OS, or move drive to another device). Another way I discovered, is to reduce the installed dummy OS to a minimum size (ie:30gb), make another partition and use ghost to copy the image there, and use https://www.boyans.net/ EasyBCD to dualboot with it. You'll end up with a dummy emergency boot OS and the main restored one.